# Is it illegal to purchase fake designer handbags from street sellers in Spain?

Tags: legal, spain

Is it illegal to purchase fake designer handbags from street sellers in Spain?

Related:

- [Can u get fake designer handbags in Spain?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100714140039AAl4EN4) at Yahoo
- [Replicas or Fake designer products?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070731125001AABrJS8) at Yahoo
- [Why are street sellers of fakes not prosecuted in Italy/Spain?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121006093412AAIOMTr) at Yahoo
- [Is it illegal to buy knock off handbags?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080124121410AAnQts8) at Yahoo
- [Is it legal to buy fake designer bags in US?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110406200043AAFSA62) at Yahoo

Comment: Very probably it's ilegal to sell them. To buy them I would say not. what leads you to that believe?

Comment: You need to worry about whether its legal to get them BACK into your country. Counterfeit items may not always put you in the pokey, but they are subject to confiscation by customs in most countries.

Comment: There are mixed opinion about it, promoting crime, copyright theft, possession of fake, stolen goods, etc. Shouldn't be the same as it's illegal to buy or downloading pirated DVDs?

Comment: US Customs, for instance, is well known to interdict such items and even has [a special web site](http://www.stopfakes.gov/) about counterfeit goods. Such are also [banned from import to the UK](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/customs/banned-restricted.htm).

Comment: Sell - probably. Buy - possibly not. Take through customs out of Spain - YMMV guess only. Take into many countries - good luck with that.

Comment: @nsn it's illegal to possess them. Whether you're buying or selling is in that irrelevant (though additional criminal charges might well apply to sellers).

Comment: @jwenting probably you're right, but I don't know how it is in detail. I just told what I knew. It's very uncommon to see those in Spain and if the sellers are usually worried  to be caught I never saw a buyer running away :)

Comment: I was in a shop in Thailand with female relatives, which sold handbags "inspired" by designer handbags. Decent quality as far as I can judge and not cheap. They had some originals in the shop so they could show there were clear and intentional differences. Enough so they could say with a straight face they were not selling fakes.

Comment: I think there's a distinction to be made between knock-off (tricking people into thinking you're wearing a name brand), counterfeit (trying a *buyer* into thinking they're buying a name brand) and copyright infringement. People here seem to be blurring these three concepts.

Comment: As Accumulation said, I seem to remember that (at least in France but Spain law should be similar, as it is EU), it depends whether you don't know it is fake (you are a victim) or you know it (you are participating in an illegal activity and benefiting from it). Police/customs may have difficulties to prove the latter, but remember that police patrols in these areas and may catch you in the act, or that the context may make you accomplice: if you buy a Louis Vuitton bag for 10 euros in the street, you should know there is something fishy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's illegal but it's also very improbable that you will get fined for doing it. However, it's also illegal to get those items into other countries like Holland, Italy, US, UK etc... if you get caught there, you WILL get fined.

---

This is the link for Spain, I couldn't find it in English but you can use Google translate: http://www.policia.es/org_central/judicial/udev/bcde_prop_intelec_indust.html. It is the site for the Police and they have a special section of their police force to prosecute crimes related to product falsification (industrial and intellectual property crimes).

Comment: How do you know? Can you link any source, please?

Comment: This is the link for Spain, I couldn't find it in English but you can use Google translate: http://www.policia.es/org_central/judicial/udev/bcde_prop_intelec_indust.html. It is the site for the Police and they have a special section of their police force to prosecute crimes related to product falsification (industrial and intellectual property crimes).

Comment: Translated version: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.policia.es%2Forg_central%2Fjudicial%2Fudev%2Fbcde_prop_intelec_indust.html&edit-text=

Comment: But as I said, you can probably get away with it (which is morally wrong by the way) but you cannot take those goods out of Spain without facing serious trouble!

Comment: I read the translated source and it doesn't look like it's illegal to by these items. The police recommend that you don't buy such items but the first section only targets manufacturing and distribution. If you're buying for your personal use, I don't think that qualifies as distribution.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes.

There's also an implicit question as to whether that is enforced and what the penalty is, and here is where it gets complicated. This activity is regulated at the local level, so the fines and the enforcement vary from town to town.

For example, a quick Google search turns up news reports from July 2018 when the town of Peñíscola ran a campaign targetting this activity and fined about 100 purchasers in 2 months between 50€ and 1500€ each.